# Error must have class type

Tags: c++, types, expression

I'm kinda new in *C++* and when trying to compile this code I get and error that I do not know how to fix:

```
int main()
{
    typedef pair<int,int> nodo;
    int x;
    cin >> x; 
    int *g;                
    g = new int[x];   

    vector <nodo> g;


    g[1].push_back(nodo(2,5));
    g[1].push_back(nodo(3,10));
    g[3].push_back(nodo(2,12));
    g[2].push_back(nodo(4,1));
    g[4].push_back(nodo(3,2));

    for (int i = 1; i <=4; ++i){
        //    cout << i << " -> ";
        for (int j = 0; j<g[i].size(); ++j){
            //    cout << g[i][j].first << " c: " << g[i][j].second << " ";    
        }
        //   cout << endl;
    }

    dijkstra(1, x);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Error: Expression must have a class type.
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: **PLEASE** do **NOT** use `system("pause");`... [just don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I am getting the error here: g[1].push_back(nodo(2,5));
    g[1].push_back(nodo(3,10));
    g[3].push_back(nodo(2,12));
    g[2].push_back(nodo(4,1));
    g[4].push_back(nodo(3,2));

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli what's so wrong with it? is it a *slow* **pause**?

Comment: @Abyx Unix-like systems don't have it.

Comment: @NicolásMúnera Usually you want to put the error you are seeing in the question itself, it is impossible to read in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things named `g`:

```
int* g;
```

and

```
vector <nodo> g;
```

This wouldn't even compile.

It looks like you want an array of vectors, in which case you need something like

```
std::vector<std::vector<nodo> > g(x); // size x vector of vectors.
```

Then you can do this type of thing:

```
g[1].push_back(nodo(2,5));
g[1].push_back(nodo(3,10));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
int *g;
g = new int[x];
vector <nodo> g; // ERROR: Redeclaration!
```

You are first declaring `g` to be of type `int*`, and then you re-declare it to be of type `vector<nodo>`. This is illegal.

Moreover, you need to have a `using namespace std` directive if you want to omit the `std::` qualification for types in the standard namespace. I do not suggest you using that though. Much better explicitly specifying `std::`, or rather use specific `using` declarations.

For instance:

```
    typedef std::pair<int,int> nodo;
//          ^^^^^
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
//  ^^^^^
    int *g;
    g = new int[x];

    std::vector <nodo> g;
//  ^^^^^
```

Also make sure you are importing all the necessary standard headers:

```
    Type     |  Header
--------------------------
std::vector -> <vector>
std::pair   -> <utility>
std::cin    -> <iostream>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're redeclaring `g`, first it's an `int*` and then you make it into a `vector<int>`. I'm not sure how that got past the compiler.

Also, rather than using `nodo(1,2)` consider using `make_pair` instead. Using `new` is also considered bad practice and you should use either a dynamic container like `std::vector` or a static one like `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

`pair` is not a class because you haven't included `<utility>`

You also haven't included `<vector>` or `<iostream>`.

Comment: Based on the code he gave, he didn't include `<iostream>` or `<vector>` either.

Comment: Thanks, added them to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So this version compiles and I think this is what you meant to do:

```
// Need to include these headers
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef pair<int,int> nodo;
    int x;
    cin >> x; 
    //int *h;                
    //h = new int[x];   

    //specify size of vector
    std::vector< std::vector<nodo> > g(x);

    g[0].push_back(nodo(2,5));
    g[1].push_back(nodo(3,10));
    g[2].push_back(nodo(2,12));
    g[3].push_back(nodo(4,1));
    g[4].push_back(nodo(3,2));


    for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << i << " -> ";
        for (int j = 0; j<g[i].size(); ++j){
                cout << g[i][j].first << " c: " << g[i][j].second << " ";    
        }
         cout << endl;
    }

    //dijkstra(1, x);
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Many issues, you use `g` twice for one. I am not sure what you want to do with the `vector` but maybe you want a `vector` of `vector`s which would be more like this:

```
 std::vector< std::vector<nodo> > g(x) ;
```

Then this would make more sense:

```
 g[0].push_back(nodo(2,5)) ;
```

The first element of a `vector` is going to be at `0` not `1`.